# Clarification of meaning: "All 3-cycles are conjugate in $A_n$."

Tags: group-theory

The statement that I'm trying to understand is actually written in German:
"Alle 3-Zykel sind in $A_n$ konjugiert."

In English, I believe this to mean: "All 3-cycles are conjugate in $A_n$."

Or "All 3-cycles conjugate in $A_n$."

I think that this means the following:
$\forall \, 3$-cycles $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in S_n, \; \exists \, \sigma \in A_n$ such that $\tau_1 = \sigma \tau_2 \sigma^{-1}$.

Is this interpretation correct? Perhaps someone could provide a proof (or link to a proof) of this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what it means.

Hint: Say $\tau = (1,2,3)$. Calculate $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$.

Ok, hint for *that*: Say $\tau_2=\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$. Calculate $\tau_2(\sigma(j))$, $j=1,2,3$.